# Start CMD on set path, clean screen and show message through batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to create a .bat file which does the following:

1. Open CMD with a path set by myself.
2. Set the echo off so it doesn't show the current path I set.
3. Clear the screen so it doesn't show "Microsoft Windows [Version blah blah blah]".
4. Show a message like "Hello world".
5. Receive cmd commands in the next line.

Aditionally, if a could change the title of the window to a custom one, that'd be great (don't know if I'm asking too much, lol)

**What I've done**

All the functional part (steps 1, 2 and 3). Here's my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
START /D "C:\MyFolder\AnotherFolder\AnotherOne"
CMD /k "prompt $"
```

**Here's how I'd like it to look like:**

[image: goal]

I know little to nothing of batch programming. What I've done, I did searching the internet, however, I haven't found how to get the rest done. Can what I want be acchieved with batch code? Any help would be much appreciated and sorry for bad english.

**EDIT:** I forgot to say, I need to place a shortcut to the batchfile on my desktop and start it from there.

Answer (score 1):

don't start another cmd instance and expect to be allowed to give it some commands afterwards. It's a process on it's own. Instead start a batchfile, that does, what you want:

`start "c:\path to my batchfile\mybatch.bat`

"Mybatch.bat" could look like this:

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\users\McSullivan\"
prompt $
cls
title Custom
echo CUSTOM MESSAGE
echo Type your commands below
```

Comment: But the thing is, I need to create a shortcut to the batchfile on the desktop. How can I acchieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think most parts do not make any prolbem so I´ll skip the obvious ones (**echo off, echo, start** and **cls** will answer 3 /4  of your question).

The more difficult thing is to put a shortcut on the desktop.. the easiest way is to create an extra file that includes vbs code... just execute this file to create a shortcut and do the rest as already stated

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLinkFile = "C:\MyShortcut.LNK"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
    oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Batch\mybatch.bat"
oLink.Save
```

In the end you will habe the "myBatch.bat" and "myBatch.vbs" with the few lines above

you can also specify the shortcut parameters with

```
 oLink.Arguments = ""
 oLink.Description = "MyBatch"   
 oLink.HotKey = "ALT+CTRL+B"
 oLink.IconLocation = "somefile.exe, 2"
 oLink.WindowStyle = "1"   
 oLink.WorkingDirectory = "C:\batch"
```